# cannot count the number of results in a php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a "People you may know" script in php. I have 2 tables, **users(user_id, name, surname, email, profile)** and table **friends(friends_id, user_one, user_two)**. I use the following script in order to select people that are friends of my friends:

```
<?php

$friends_of_friends = mysql_query(" SELECT u.*
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_one as user_id
    FROM friends
    WHERE user_two IN (SELECT user_one as user_id
        FROM friends
        WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT user_two
        FROM friends
        WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
               )
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT DISTINCT user_two
    FROM friends
    WHERE user_one IN (SELECT user_one as user_id
              FROM friends
              WHERE user_two = '$session_user_id'
              UNION DISTINCT
              SELECT user_two
              FROM friends
              WHERE user_one = '$session_user_id'
               )
         ) f
         JOIN users u
         ON u.user_id = f.user_id  ORDER BY `surname` ASC ");


while ($run_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_of_friends)) {
$friend_friend_id = $run_friends['user_id'];


    // friends of my friends that are not my friends
    $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two='$friend_friend_id') OR (user_one='$friend_friend_id' AND user_two='$session_user_id')  ");

        if(mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) != 1){ 

           $not_friends = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE (`user_id`='$friend_friend_id' and `user_id`!='$session_user_id')   ");

           while ($run_not_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($not_friends)) {                                                  
            $not_friend_id = $run_not_friends['user_id'];
           }

        }//end if

 }//end while

?>
```

My code works succesfully. The only problem is that after I get all the people that I want using this script, I cannot count their number. I have used:

```
$num_of_people=mysql_num_rows($not_friends);
echo"$num_of_people";
```

I am always getting 1. Any idea how can I count this amount of people(friends of my friends that are not my friends).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shankar Damodaran is right use this

```
$i=0;
while ($run_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_of_friends)) {
$friend_friend_id = $run_friends['user_id'];


    // friends of my friends that are not my friends
    $check_friend_query = mysql_query("  SELECT friends_id from friends WHERE  (user_one='$session_user_id' AND user_two='$friend_friend_id') OR (user_one='$friend_friend_id' AND user_two='$session_user_id')  ");

        if(mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) != 1){ 

           $not_friends = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `email`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE (`user_id`='$friend_friend_id' and `user_id`!='$session_user_id')   ");

           if(mysql_num_rows($not_friends)) i++;
        }//end if

 }//end while

echo $i;
```

Comment: you saved me a lot of time friend. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make use of a **`counter variable`** here like this

```
$i=0; // I have added here

while ($run_friends= mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_of_friends)) {
$friend_friend_id = $run_friends['user_id'];

$i++;// Increment the var

}//end while
echo $i;//Total number of users
?>
```

Comment: I get a number (different from 1 that I use to get) but it is not correct still. For example have 2 people and it gives number 5

Answer (score 0):

$num_of_people=mysql_num_rows($not_friends);
echo"$num_of_people";

You are printing it wrong, that's a string not the variable.

- Try this way.

  echo $num_of_people;